# Ionic native dialogs show html formatted message

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

With the following approach, I could not get the expected output.

```
import { Dialogs } from '@ionic-native/dialogs';

constructor(private dialogs: Dialogs) { }

...

this.dialogs.alert('<h1>Hello</h1> world <br> Hello')
  .then(() => console.log('Dialog dismissed'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error displaying dialog', e));
```

Expected Output :

## Hello

world 
 Hello

Current output :

```
<h1>Hello</h1> world <br> Hello
```

Any suggestions would be appreciable.

**UPDATE**

As requested by @PareshGami, I updated the [`Notification.java`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/2bc54cf62c5f3bff70242d1ef381d19786cb9611/src/android/Notification.java#L169) as below :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   dlg.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(message, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
   dlg.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(message));
}
```

And built the project with

```
ionic cordova build android
```

But still could not get the expected html formatted output.

Comment: You need to change some line for code in an Android plugin for that

Comment: @PareshGami Which line ??

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/src/android/Notification.java Line Number: 169. I think tha might be help Html.fromHtml()

Comment: @PareshGami I tried, but did not work as expected. Still cannot get the html formatted output. :(